# MBR Boot sector partition error

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, gparted

After suffering a virus attack on my current laptop there was still found a md5 hash error located on the mbr boot hard drive sector, then I decided to use gparted to perform a new partition on the current installed ssd hard drive and rebuild the mbr boot on whole.

After this I have received as a problem while trying to reinstall my former installed windows 10 version an error following as 0xc000000f BCD error, for my understanding the boot sector is currently damaged and not able to follow up without a boot repair.

At the moment I have used the testdisk tool located with the gparted terminal access and apparently there were found some partition errors or not really well fixed HD sectors.

For now I have been not able to find a solution to fix this problem now in order to reconfigure correctly the partition and mbr boot structure with aim to reinstall properly a new windows OS version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to boot Windows 10 ISO via USB, get into the Console and put this commands:

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

You can also consider to put this command also:
    bootsect /nt60 ALL

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of the above mentioned commands the problem lays with the problem that by the moment I can only run commands through the Gparted Linux console.there I have only found out how to reset the partitions and recover the mbr boot but I have failed on the attempt so far, that would be helpful only on case to reach a cmd modus console input to generate a new boot sector.